# Java and Selenium: Trouble getting contents of input field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problems getting the text contents of an input field. I seem to only be getting the things around it with the method I'm using.

Snippet from the page:

(It's a list of itemsincluding an input field in each row.)

[image]

The markup:

```
<ul class="budsjett budsjett--kompakt" id="sifobudsjett">
   <li class="budsjett-post ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" id="SIFO_mat">
      <div class="felt" >
         <div class="felt-indre">
            <div id="SIFO_mat-farge" class="sifo-farge farge-graa"></div>
               <span class="budsjett-post-beskrivelse" >
                  <span tabindex="0" title="Vis hjelpetekst" role="button">
                     <span class="hjelpetekst-label" >Mat og drikke</span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="sifo-hjelp" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </span>
            </span>
            <span class="budsjett-post-verdi">               
               <span class="budsjett-post-verdi-endret" ng-show="!skrivebeskyttet" aria-hidden="false" style="">
                  <input id="SIFO_mat-input" name="SIFO_mat" type="number">
                  <span class="felt-enhet"><abbr id="SIFO_mat-enhet" title="kroner" translate=""><span class="ng-scope">kr</span></abbr></span>
                  </span>
               </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The code:

```
List<WebElement> sifoliste = driver.findElement(By.id("sifobudsjett")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

Result of first element: "Mat og drikke".

```
List<WebElement> sifoliste = driver.findElement(By.id("sifobudsjett")).findElements(By.tagName("input"));
```

Result of first element: ""

```
List<WebElement> sifoliste = driver.findElement(By.id("sifobudsjett")).findElements(By.className("budsjett-post-verdi-endret"));
```

Result of first element: "kr"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` tag doesn't have text, what you see in the UI is kept in the `value` attribute. It exists even if you can't see it in the html

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SIFO_mat-input")).getAttribute("value");
```

For all the `<input>`s

```
List<WebElement> sifoliste = driver.findElement(By.id("sifobudsjett")).findElements(By.tagName("input"));
String text = sifoliste.get(0).getAttribute("value"); // 2790
```

Comment: But I'm not trying to find one specific element, so I cannot use the id "SIFO_mat-input"). I'm using findelEmentS to get a list of all the elements and the input values.

Comment: @Hfrav the difference is how you get the text, the rest you can do in the same way. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Guy I believe there is a typo in your example `String text = sifoliste[0].getAttribute("value");` should be `String text = sifoliste.get(0).getAttribute("value");`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String inputValue = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input")).getAttribute("value");
```